# PagerTitleStrip without title bar indicator

Tags: android, swipe, strip

I'm using **PagerTitleStrip** for first time run app tutorial. 
Since I need to see the content of the whole full screen in the activity below, I would like to hide the title bar of the PagerTitleStrip (the bar where the steps number are showed).
How to do this ?

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
       android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:background="#000000"
       android:paddingBottom="4dp"
       android:paddingTop="4dp"
       android:textColor="#fff" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: "the bar where the steps number are showed" -- what are "the steps number"? Please consider uploading a screenshot somewhere and linking to it from your question, so we have some idea what you are referring to.

Comment: http://lauriefurman.com/pagertitlestrip.java-718.jpg

Comment: That looks a lot more like action bar tabs than `PagerTitleStrip`. Even if it is `PagerTitleStrip`, then it *is* `PagerTitleStrip`. If you want to get rid of the titles, get rid of the `PagerTitleStrip` entirely.

Comment: how can I slide pages without PagerTitleStrip so ?

Comment: The user cannot interact with a `PagerTitleStrip`. It is for display only. There are other `ViewPager` indicators that are tabs, but your question indicates that you do not want the tabs. User can always page through the `ViewPager` using horizontal swipe gestures.

Comment: thank you, this was the answer I was looking for