# Hide adjacent tabs titles in PagerTitleStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have an app that displays tabs, that you can scroll horizontally with the help of a *ViewPager*.

My question is : is there a way to **hide the adjacent tabs titles** in a *PagerTitleStrip*  ?

I've been so far unable to find a way to do that either dynamically or via XML...

Thanks in advance !

P.S. : I'd like to post a picture to illustrate the issue, but it seems my reputation is too low... Sorry about that.

Edit : on this image http://oi59.tinypic.com/2lm2ouh.jpg I'd like to hide the "Today" and "The day before" texts. Thank you CFlex for the hint !

Comment: You can post a link to your image though.

Comment: Maybe you don't need a PagerTitleStrip. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214762/pagertitlestrip-without-title-bar-indicator

Comment: Yeah, I already went through that answer. But I do need a *PageTitleStrip*...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I wanted to add the approach I used to potentially save someone else some time.

```
pagerTitleStrip.setNonPrimaryAlpha(0F);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question may be old, but still relevant. I got the question while programming two pagers side-by-side and there it is quite unelegant to have the next and before labels between the pagers. But there is a simple solution for that:

- `addOnPageChangeListener` for one of the pagers and fill a member variable of your fragment or activity class with the current position of the pager.

In the `FragmentPagerAdapter` is the function `getPageTitle(int position)` which actually asks for the page title to display *every time the pager changes positions*, and this up to three times for the current, previous and next position.

So, now you know on what position you are and can distinguish which are the requests for the previous and next titles and for these you can simply return an empty string. In the case of the original question:

```
private int mPagerPos = 0;
ViewPager mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);

mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mPagerPos = position;
    }

});

class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if ( mPagerPos > position ) { return ""; } // title for previous tab
        else if ( mPagerPos == position ) { ... } // title for current tab
        else if ( mPagerPos < position ) { return ""; } // title for next tab
    }
}
```